# How do I dynamically allocate space in a template class without violating const restrictions?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is my first experience with templates, consider this a newbie question (please).

What I would like to do is to keep the convenience of using operator[] but structure the function to dynamic array growth, e.g., vector. I keep getting trashed with const violation errors. I would have preferred to use vector but I cam across a runtime error whenever I did an `x[ndx] = value`. I finally gave up and am trying to create my own version of vector.

The example code is:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class  Vector {
   private:
      long _ndx = 0;
      T*    _ptr;                               // storage for T objects
   public:
      Vector() { }
      T&   operator[](const long ndx) { _ndx = ndx; return _ptr[ndx]; }
};

#endif   // VECTOR_H



# include <iostream>
# include "Vector.h"

using namespace std;

struct X {
   long a;
   long b;
   void toString() { cout << a << " " << b << endl; }
};

class Y {
private:
   long _ndx =0;
   Vector<X*> word;
public:
   Y() { }
   X* operator[](const long ndx) const {  return word[ndx]; }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   Y y;
   X* x = y[0];
}
```

The error is:

```
    main.cpp:20:58: error: passing 'const Vector<X*>' as 'this' argument
    discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
    X* operator[](const long ndx) const {  return word[ndx]; }

   In file included from main.cpp:4:0: Vector.h:13:12: note:   in call to 'T& Vector<T>::operator[](long int) [with T = X*]'
   T&   operator[](const long ndx) { _ndx = ndx; return _ptr[ndx]; }
```

From other questions on stackoverflow I understand the error. I haven't been able to get -fpermissive to work. The actual code changes Vector::operator[] to do two things, adjust the high water mark for _ndx and, when _ndx exceeds some threshold, increase the vector size, here T* _ptr, copy the old information into the new space and delete the vector and use the new space. I can't figure how to do this 'gracefully'.

Answer (score 2):

If we disregard the appropriateness of the design for a moment, you can change `ndx_` to be a `mutable` member and change the member function to be a `const` member function to get `const` reference to the member. You can add a non-`const` member function to get a non-`const` reference to allow you to modify the contents of a vector using the array operator.

```
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class  Vector {
   private:

      // |
      // v
      mutable long _ndx = 0;

      T*    _ptr;                               // storage for T objects
   public:
      Vector() { }

      // The const version
      // |                                 |
      // v                                 v
      T const&  operator[](const long ndx) const { _ndx = ndx; return _ptr[ndx]; }

      // The non-const version
      T&  operator[](const long ndx) { _ndx = ndx; return _ptr[ndx]; }
 };
```

Comment: tAvoiding the design is indeed wise and judicious. Now comes an additional issue. in Vector<T>operator[] when ndx exceeds the current size of the allocated space a non-const function is called (getSpace()) to expand the space. Warning messages are issued.Any way of altering the code so warning messages are not issued?

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez  `_ptr` also to be `mutable`.